# TextInputLayout hint not working when using databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, viewmodel, android-textinputedittext

I am using databinding together with the TextInputLayout/TextInputEditText combo as shown in the xml.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/lastname_input_layout"
                style="@style/TextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstname_input_layout"
                app:visible="@{viewModel.showFields}">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/lastname_input"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/lastname"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:text="@={viewModel.lastName}"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Input" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/email_input_layout"
                style="@style/TextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lastname_input_layout"
                app:visible="@{viewModel.showFields}">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/email_input"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@{viewModel.watchMediaTextHint}"
                    android:inputType="@{viewModel.watchMediaInputType}"
                    android:text="@={viewModel.mediaText}"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Input" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, both fields are theoretically the same, the only difference is that one of them has the `hint` text given with a string resource, the other one with a databinding. Both have the same style, text appearance and so on, yet, the hint on the `TextInputEditText` using the databinding has different color. Also, when the view gets focus, the label doesn't animate up, as it does with the first field.

Setting the hint with a string resource gets this behavior to go back to normal, any ideas on why is this anomaly happening? I would prefer to solve this with a databinding rather than a programmatic solution.

Thanks.

Comment: The `hint` attribute needs to go on the `<TextInputLayout>`, instead of the `<TextInputEditText>`. It's only set from that attribute on the `<TextInputEditText>` once, when it's added during inflation. After that, setting the hint on the `EditText` in code has no effect on the `TextInputLayout`'s hint

Comment: @MikeM. You nailed it, thank you very much! Didn't know this particular thing of the hint, very interesting indeed.

Answer (score 2):

The `hint` attribute only works in combination with databinding, if it is set to `<TextInputLayout>` instead of `<TextInputEditText>`.

The `<TextInputEditText>`s `hint` attribute is only applied once during inflation and thereby will not be updated/applied when used in combination with databinding.

---

Heads up for @Mike M.'s comment. I converted it as an answer, in order to be found more easily by others.